# Jensen-Shannon Divergence: Samples with different sizes

Tags: machine-learning

I have multiple samples of a discrete variable. For each sample I see the frequency of each value of the variable. I am taking one sample to be my benchmark, call it Q. I want to estimate the distance between Q and all other samples.

To do so, I am using the Jensen-Shannon Divergence. However, my samples are in different sizes. From my understanding, sample with a smaller size will have a bigger JSD. Is this true? If so, how can I account for this, so I will have comparable measures metric accross different samples?

Thank you!